# Calculated column to display the next 8 business hours

Tags: calculated-column

In one of the column I am having the current date and time based on that using calculated column I have to show the date and time of the next 8 business hours date and time.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

tryout this.

```
=[Start Date]+(8/24)
```

Comment: Hi Malin,while adding the item it self i required the next 8 business hours in the other coumn not to update the column hourly

Comment: Oh k. Then it can be done using an event receiver.

Comment: Is there any formula to calculate the next 8 business hours and display that make that field read only and display at the time of entering the form

Comment: @Bharathi, calculated columns does not work that way, they update their values only on edit / create of the list item

Comment: @Robert,my reqirement is to display the next 8 business hours using the calculated column while creating the item.I want the formula for that calculated column to dispaly the next 8 business hours date and time in that column

Comment: Then you will have to create a custom form or modify the New Item form with some JavaScript.

Comment: So you just want it to display what 8 hours would be from the item created time, and that never changes?

Comment: yes,it must be next 8 business hours of the request created is it possible to create using the calculated column?we have to put a formula for that based on the created field